# Passing variable amount of objects as reference to a class

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I have library that im using to load images. The library makes class objects out of the files and has their own drawing functions. Im trying to build a class that can handle these objects and implement some simple logic once im done loading my files. What would be a good way to pass them as reference or pointer to my handling class?

This is what i got so far:

1) Passing them as reference one by one. When i add a file i will always have to write the new file to my class definition.

2) Loading all the objects into array and pass that as reference. I still have to set the class defition so that i know how many items are in the array. But what if i have different amount files to load at various steps of my program? Writing many constructor/function overloads doesnt seem like a right way to do it.

I searched for the weekend and didnt really find any solutions to this so any points and tips would be welcome. Oh and im pretty new to C++ so consider my knowledge limited. I can grasp the idea what the pointers and references are but implementing things with them are slow.

So to repeat my question. What would be a good way to pass variable amount of objects as reference or pointer to my handling class?

Comment: Read up on `std::vector`. As a first approximation, it's kind of like an array, but it's much more flexible and naturally handles the case of not knowing how many elements you need to start with, it can dynamically grow.

Comment: Perhaps a vector or list? Who is in charge of allocating the objects? Do you create the object and pass to the library to populate, or does the library create and populate the object and return it?

Comment: seems std::vector works good without defining the amount of data there will be in class definition =) thanks, rest of the week saved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make your function look like this:

```
void my_function(std::vector<SomeObject *> &objs) {
   // ...
}
```

and you can then iterate over the objs vector using an Iterator, or just check

```
objs.size()
```

see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: is there any difference if i use it like this my_function(std::vector<SomeObject> &objs)

Comment: <SomeObject&> doesnt seem to work but leaving the reference mark out works. uh thanks from the answers!

Comment: @John It should be `std::vector<SomeObject> &objs`

Comment: @John whoops - I got a bit carried away with all the references. You can use std::vector<SomeObject *>  or  std::vector<SomeObject> as Neil mentions.

Answer (score 0):

You did not include source code details about your issue but your solution # 2 should be fine and you can just pass an `int` variable to hold the number of elements in the array.